# How can I use the C modf function in php?

Tags: php, c

There does not appear to be one?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what could you possibly make you want to port a C program to PHP?

Comment: Its a program that performs calculations for earth orbit satellites, the program is 16 bit and will not work on x64 but I would prefer to have a PHP web based version. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use PHP's [fmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php).

Comment: killed my script - times out?

Comment: That I'm not sure about, how many times do you call this function?  Also, if you anticipate that the running time of our script will be a long time make sure you change PHP's script time out using set_time_limit

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer

```
function modf($x, &$ipart)
{
 $ipart = (int) $x;
 return $x - $ipart;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Which is equivalent to `fmod($x, 1);`.